# php include inside .tpl.php template file

Tags: theming

I have 2 template files where I want to use a common piece of template code. Is it ok to do an include of the chunk of template code I want to use?

Example model.tpl.php:

```
include('/path/to/template.php.tpl');
<!-- Other Template Code -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its better to modify the shared template inside `hook_theme` and use Drupal theme engine:

```
<?php print theme('your_shared_template_file', $args); ?>
```